# Play 2.5.4 application not starting on Heroku

Tags: heroku, playframework

I'm trying to deploy a play 2.5.4 application, but it's not working.

Here is how my procfile looks like :

```
web: target/universal/stage/bin/playproject
```

plugins.sbt

```
// The Play plugin

    addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.5.4")
```

build.sbt

```
    name := """playproject"""

    scalaVersion in ThisBuild := "2.11.8"
....
```

On heroku here are the logs :

[image]

Any idea what's the problem ?

Comment: Can you check what bin scripts exist on heroku by running `heroku run ls target/universal/stage/bin/`? Those scripts should be generated by `sbt stage`

Answer (score 0):

If you try to build your project, e.g try `sbt stage`, you will see, that there is no `target/universal/stage/bin/playproject` under the root folder of your project. Real Play app you have under `examples` folder, so in your **Procfile** you need to specify:

```
web: examples/target/universal/stage/bin/examples
```